# OSError while deploying Django in App Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So trying to deploy my Django app in App Engine Flexible, I get the following error:

```html
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'nlp\light\Fine_tuned_spacy_model\'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

My Django app is working fine localy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had encountered the same problem, I think you should specify the full path when using spacy.load

Try adding **/home/vmagent/app/** to the beginning of your path.